# Print Result not consist with the original XPS file

Tags: printing, printdialog

I'm trying to print my own XPS file to the printer with PrintDialog. But the print result is not the same as the original XPS. The words in the XPS are missing and there is no text displayed in the print result

I have tried making some changes on the PrintTicket but could not get the correct print output.

How shall I set up the printdialog to get the correct print result? Or is there any other way to do the printing in WPF project?

Sample Code.

```
   public void Print()
    {
        string fileName = "D:\\PAM\\in.xps";

        XpsDocument xpsFile = new XpsDocument(fileName, FileAccess.ReadWrite);

        PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog();
        printDialog.ShowDialog();
        printDialog.PrintTicket.PageOrientation = PageOrientation.Landscape;
        printDialog.PrintTicket.OutputQuality = System.Printing.OutputQuality.High;
        printDialog.PrintTicket.OutputColor = System.Printing.OutputColor.Color;
        printDialog.PrintDocument(xpsFile.GetFixedDocumentSequence().DocumentPaginator, "");

        xpsFile.Close();

    }
```

Screen shot of part of Original XPS

Print Result

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the user actually exists--but for those who stumbled upon this question, printing an XPS file would typically be done with the XpsDocumentWriter.

[How to: Programmatically Print XPS Files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969772%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Note that all printers are different and it may be required to consult the manufacturer of the printer to debug issues.  What I have found is, not all printers support XPS document printing.

In one interesting case, I was printing on a Xerox printer, with the PCL print driver installed.  When I looked at `PrintDialog.PrintQueue.IsXps` I saw that it was equal to false.  Then I learned there is a specific XPS printer driver for the printer. I installed that driver--which added another printer to my printer list--and printed using that driver, and `IsXps` was equal to true.  This is one of the many gotchas in the printer world.